# python pdfkit: increase font size

Tags: python, python-2.7, pdf, pdfkit

I transformed an HTML file into a pdf simply by:

```
pdfkit.from_file("cpp.html",'cpp.pdf')
```

Problem is that the font-size is very small.

How to increase the font-size (both of headers and paragraphs) using pdfkit? Obviously I want the headers font to remain bigger than the paragraphs font.

I guess I have to tweak the options, but I can't find how.

Comment: Did you try what the [doc page](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pdfkit)  suggests; passing options? There is a `header-font-size` parameter you could pass.

Comment: @ako I'm sorry, but in that page I don't see `header-font-size` anywhere :/
Anyways, what's the unit of measure I have to use? Because I've tried px and em but they don't work

Comment: Well, I don't know the library. I only go with what I can see from 30 seconds of looking at the doc page. The page I referred to says: "You can specify all wkhtmltopdf options," at which point it links you to the page for the underlying library. From there, it says font size is default 12. There is also a fair chance that mileage may vary, depending on which platform you are on.

Answer (score 9):

In my case manually setting dpi helped.

```
options = {
    'dpi':96,
}
pdfkit.from_url(url,out_file,options=options)
```

Answer (score 2):

There's also a zoom option, which solved the problem for me. (Takes a Float)

```
    options = {
    'zoom': 2,
}
pdfkit.from_url(url,out_file,options=options)
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried both, zoom and dpi, but the one that worked best for me is

```
options = {
    'minimum-font-size': "20",
}
```

or whichever value

additionally you can pass any of these parameters from wkhtml as options to pdfkit - https://wkhtmltopdf.org/usage/wkhtmltopdf.txt